# Cite R packages without direct citation, in beamer

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, r

I would like to cite R packages we did for a group work, without direct citation, in my beamer presentation: I would like to have a final frame (or group of frames) that recap all the packages used. R exports the correct citations in Bibtex format so I would like to know how do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you know how compile a .Rnw file with `knitr` and biblatex, just compliging this file all the references of non-base attached packages in the R session are stored automatically in a .bib file and then you can use as usual with BibTex, or as in this example, with biblatex and `biber`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,message=F>>=
# R packages loaded only to test their references
library(xtable)
library(stargazer)
library(ggplot2)
library(pscl)
write_bib(names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs),file="test.bib")
@
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]{References}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Fran, however if I use this code (of course changing the .bib file) it gives me only 3 packages, that I did not use...

Comment: EDIT: no I figured out my mates did not export it in .rnw... we still need to work on it

Comment: @LucaCapena. Sure that you have all these packages installed?  You have modified something in my example? Your R is updated? Without see the real code and the real output  is a guessing game. Edit your question to show both the output and the code that you have used, except if it is just exactly the code of my answer).